# ListView displays different items than what is in the holder

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, baseadapter

I have a custom adapter that extends the baseadapter. It has a variety of different layouts some with thumbnails some without. When I add a new item that is the same type as the one before the row displays the same values. But when I check what is set in the holder it tells me that the correct items are set.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int layoutType = getItemViewType(position);
    ListViewRow item = null;

    if(convertView == null) {
        item = atIndex(position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = getConvertView(layoutType, parent);//ViewHolder items declared here
        convertView.setTag(-1, holder);
    }
    else if(!viewMatchesType(layoutType, convertView.getId())){
        item = atIndex(position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = getConvertView(layoutType, parent);//ViewHolder items declared here
        convertView.setTag(-1, holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(-1);
        item = atIndex(position);
    }

    setDisplay(item, convertView);//I set values here

    if(holder.tv_name.getText() != item.getName()) {
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    return convertView;
}

//For performance, ui elements are saved in a holder
private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView iv_thumbnail;
    public TextView tv_name;
}
```

Comment: where are you declaring the items in `veiwholder`?

Comment: Try setting the contents directly instead of just setting your viewholder to your tag

Comment: In getConvertView I inflate the proper layout and assign the holder contents (findViewById). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

i havent really found optimal solution for this problem myself, but removing this if condition seems to work for me. Instead of this

```
if(convertView == null) {
    item = atIndex(position);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = getConvertView(layoutType, parent);//ViewHolder items declared here
    convertView.setTag(-1, holder);
}
```

just use this

```
    item = atIndex(position);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = getConvertView(layoutType, parent);//ViewHolder items declared here
    convertView.setTag(-1, holder);
```

it sure is heavy on memory, but i haven't really found any other solution.

Comment: yes it does.... i couldnt make it work with holder, and reusing the views... so i just populated the data each time and displayed it. searched about it for quiet a while but couldnt get any solution. so i ended up deleting the if condition  and not using holder.